# Oracle - Dealing with NULLS in DENSE_RANK

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table structure

```
+----------------+----------------+
|      DATE      |      VALUE     |
|----------------|----------------|
|  2015-01-01    |       5        |
|  2015-01-02    |       4        |
|  2015-01-03    |      NULL      |
|  2015-02-10    |       2        |
|  2015-02-25    |       1        |
+----------------+----------------+
```

I'm trying to get the most recent **non null** value within each month. In this case it would be this:

```
+----------------+----------------+
|      MONTH     |      VALUE     |
|----------------|----------------|
|     2015-01    |       4        |
|     2015-02    |       1        |
+----------------+----------------+
```

I've tried DENSE_RANK but i'm having a difficult time dealing with the null values.

Using:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(date,'YYYY-MM'),
MAX(value) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY date DESC)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(date,'YYYY-MM')
```

I'm getting

```
+----------------+----------------+
|      MONTH     |      VALUE     |
|----------------|----------------|
|     2015-01    |      NULL      |
|     2015-02    |       1        |
+----------------+----------------+
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong.
Can you help me figure this out?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Unfortunately, adding the condition

```
"WHERE value IS NOT NULL"
```

can't be applied to my situation.

Comment: I dont know if there is an error, but you say `trying to get the most recent ` but you use `MAX(Value)` instead `MAX(Month)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `MAX() KEEP` doesn't have an `IGNORE NULLS` clause, as far as I know.  But `LAST_VALUE` does.  So, how about this:

```
SELECT mth,
       MAX (last_val)
FROM   (SELECT TO_CHAR (d, 'YYYY-MM') mth,
               d,
               n,
               LAST_VALUE (
                 n IGNORE NULLS)
               OVER (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR (d, 'YYYY-MM')
                     ORDER BY d ASC
                     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
                 last_val
        FROM   matt_test)
GROUP BY mth
```

Comment: Thanks for the check.  I just thought of this this morning.  You might also, in your original query, just replace `MAX(value) KEEP...` with `MAX(NVL(value, some_super_low_value)) KEEP...`.  I'm not in front of an Oracle instance right now, but if it works it'd be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

This solution eliminates null values and uses `row_number` to get the latest date and the corresponding value for each month.

```
select myr, value
from (
SELECT date, value,TO_CHAR(date,'YYYY-MM') myr,
row_number() over(partition by TO_CHAR(date,'YYYY-MM') order by date desc) rn 
FROM mytable
where value is not null) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately that is not an option for my case. I'll clarify that in the main post.

Comment: I think you have it vkp. Just use the `NULLS LAST` on your version.

Answer (score 0):

I have a personal averseness to construction like `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ... FROM ...)`, so this is my proposal:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
TRUNC(THE_DATE, 'MM') AS MONTH,
FIRST_VALUE(THE_VALUE IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY TRUNC(THE_DATE, 'MM') ORDER BY THE_VALUE) AS VALUE
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Comment: Great answer. Unfortunately Matthew's answer is a better fit for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could not use `LAST_VALUE` because of Group By and many other reasons.
So this worked for me, example line:

```
SELECT
  MAX(the_value) KEEP (dense_rank LAST ORDER BY (CASE WHEN the_value IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) NULLS FIRST, the_date) the_value
FROM ...
```

or like that:

```
SELECT
  MAX(the_value) KEEP (dense_rank FIRST ORDER BY (CASE WHEN the_value IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) NULLS LAST, the_date DESC) the_value
FROM ...
```